# opencv2/opencv.hpp missing on vc2008 Express

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
I'm trying to run the program ssimTest found at this URL:

http://nma.web.nitech.ac.jp/fukushima/opencv/ssim/ssim-e.html

I have the same environment, OpenCV2.1 and VC2008 Express.
When I compile, I see this:

c:\users\asus24\documents\visual studio 2008\projects\ssimtest\ssimtest\main.cpp(2) : fatal error C1083: Impossible open the include file 'opencv2/opencv.hpp': No such file or directory

And this file does not exist.

Some friends of other list have suggested to me to ask here.

Also I have see the [www.ros.org](http://www.ros.org) pages and the Win download seems to be compiled
with MinGW and CMake. As I have VC2008 Express now I'm in confusion and totally lost.

Ciao

Leo

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10555/opencv2/opencv.hpp-missing-on-vc2008-express/) by [Leo](https://answers.ros.org/users/817/leo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2011-07-10

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You need to use a more recent version of OpenCV that has C++ bindings and the file you are mentioning. 2.3.1 got released in July 2011.

That will solve your issue but you can also file bug reports for OpenCV on:
https://code.ros.org/trac/opencv/report

---

Originally posted by [Vincent Rabaud](https://answers.ros.org/users/358/vincent-rabaud/) with karma: 1111 on 2011-09-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0